# ScrollPane doesn't allow scrolling down to see its contents

Tags: java, javafx

I have a VBox which I have added 50 Labels to. Considering it's wrapped within a ScrollPane, I thought that it would allow for me to scroll down to see the rest of the data, but it doesn't allow it.

As I'm building this through Scene Builder, it is configured as XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="454.0" prefWidth="641.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="111.0" layoutY="96.0" prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="100.0">
         <children>
            <Label contentDisplay="TOP" style="-fx-font-size: 20;" text="Stack" />
            <VBox fx:id="stackBox" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="149.0" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: lightgrey;" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox layoutX="298.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="379.0" prefWidth="198.0">
         <children>
            <Label style="-fx-font-size: 20;" text="Heap" />
            <ScrollPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="341.0" prefWidth="202.0" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS">
               <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <VBox fx:id="heapBox" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="149.0" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: lightgrey;" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is currently what it looks like:
[image]

As there are 50 elements in the VBox, it should allow for me to scroll down to see the remaining 32 elements, but as it can be seen, the scrollbar doesn't allow it.

What can be done in this circumstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `min` and `pref` size values from your `AnchorPane` inside `ScrollPane`. Then your `AnchorPane` could fit to `ScrollPane` content.

```
<AnchorPane>
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="heapBox" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="149.0" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: lightgrey;" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```